# Vertex Buffer out of memory error with small STL file

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I am getting a :

Error [Visual.cc:1876] Unable to insert mesh[Vertex Buffer: Out of memory]

error when importing a very small (384 bytes) stl file. Any chance this is some kind of underflow problem? I have other files I've generated the same way (export from solidworks) that do not have this problem.

I've uploaded the file here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/72r0t9apatlj1ft/xcone_convex.STL

It's a very simple pyramid shape. I can provide the .world file I am using if necessary.

I'm importing using:

file://xcone_convex.STL

Anyone else having this problem? Can anyone else import this file? I've also verified that the file itself is intact by importing it into Matlab with no trouble.

Thanks,
Nick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3360/vertex-buffer-out-of-memory-error-with-small-stl-file/) by [Nick Eckenstein](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/307/nick-eckenstein/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 59 on 2013-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I believe the problem is that the STL file is in binary, and Gazebo only handles ASCII STL files.

I've created a [ticket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/757/handle-binary-stl-files) to address this issue. In the meantime, try converting to ASCII.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2013-06-27**:
Is this the trick where you edit the first word 'solid' within the stl file and replace it with something of the same length, like 'robot'?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-06-27**:
Here's a fix: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/601

**Comment by [Nick Eckenstein](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/307/nick-eckenstein/) on 2013-06-27**:
Thanks, changing to ascii fixed it. The strange thing is that I've been importing binary files for a while now without any trouble. In any event, happy to see it fixed, and so quickly!

**Comment by [Nick Eckenstein](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/307/nick-eckenstein/) on 2013-07-02**:
Okay, now that I've tried to implement the fix, I've noticed that the fix does not in fact work. The STL file I was using before gives me the same error message, and the

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-07-03**:
The fix in the pull-request is not working for you, with the same STL file?

**Comment by [Nick Eckenstein](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/307/nick-eckenstein/) on 2013-07-04**:
After looking into it more, it was my fault. The fix works great. Sorry, I had tried to delete that comment...

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1096/dmngu9/) on 2015-02-07**:
i have same problem. the fix doesnt fixx anything. how did you do it please?

**Comment by [Nick Eckenstein](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/307/nick-eckenstein/) on 2015-02-10**:
My stl file was in fact saved with the wrong units. As a result it overflowed the workspace (was too large). More than likely the problem is with your stl file, either corrupt or wrong units.